# Make every <li> element different (no repeat) color from randomly generated list of colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an array of colors and then I randomized them. I want to assign different color to each list item instead of having items with the same colors or having repeated colors.

```js
const myList = document.querySelector('.myList');
const listItems = myList.querySelectorAll('li');
const itemColors = ['red', 'green', 'royalblue', 'purple','cornflowerblue', 'sienna','palevioletred','orange'];

listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  

  let randomColors = itemColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * itemColors.length)];
   item.style.color = randomColors;
  
});
```

```html
<ul class="myList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Soup</li>
  <li>Juice</li>
  <li>Beer</li>
  <li>Wine</li>
  <li>Soda</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Randomise the sort order of the array then loop through it, instead of picking a random item every iteration

Comment: This can work only if the list of colors is at least as long as the list of `<li>` elements. Then you can [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) the list of colors and assign the N-th color to the N-th `<li>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is just clone your `itemColors` and then randomly sort.

You can then use the index into this array to get the color.

Note: The random sort here is not 100% random as technically it's not using sort in the correct way, but for something like this should be fine.  Also this also assumes your array of colors is larger than the number of `li` elements.

If using sort in a way it's not meant to be used, a simple solution is to map the random value, and sort on this, this will make the sort then stable.

```
const randColors = [...itemColors]
  .map((item, index) => ({order:Math.random(), item}))
  .sort((a,b) => a.order - b.order)
  .map(i => i.item);
```

eg..

```js
const myList = document.querySelector('.myList');
const listItems = myList.querySelectorAll('li');
const itemColors = ['red', 'green', 'royalblue', 'purple','cornflowerblue', 'sienna','palevioletred','orange'];

const randColors = [...itemColors].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
   item.style.color = randColors[index];
});
```

```html
<ul class="myList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Soup</li>
  <li>Juice</li>
  <li>Beer</li>
  <li>Wine</li>
  <li>Soda</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: a function passed into Array.sort() should be [pure, stable, reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: @code_monk. I assume you didn't read my note in answer, I specifically said I'm using sort incorrectly, but for the purpose of changing colours in a list it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a Function that give you the unique index and hence you can assign the different color to each variable.
It's just a method approach. If you are interested.

```
const myList = document.querySelector('.myList');
const listItems = myList.querySelectorAll('li');
const itemColors = ['red', 'green', 'royalblue', 'purple','cornflowerblue', 'sienna','palevioletred','orange'];
console.log("This list",listItems.length)
console.log("This item",itemColors.length)
let previousIndexes = []
function ReturnUniqueIndex(lengthss){
  
    let randomNum;
    let min = 0;
    let max = lengthss;
    
  
    do {
        randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    } while (previousIndexes.includes(randomNum));

    return randomNum;
  
  
}
listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  
  previousIndexes = [...previousIndexes,index]
  let randomColors = itemColors[ReturnUniqueIndex(itemColors.length)];
   item.style.color = randomColors;
  

});
```

The HTML:

```
<ul class="myList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Soup</li>
  <li>Juice</li>
  <li>Beer</li>
  <li>Wine</li>
  <li>Soda</li>
</ul>
```